# Assign Properties from Method

Tags: c#

I have two class, base and inherited class like these

```
public class A
{
     public string Prop1 { get; set; }
} 

public class B : A
{
     public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have a method which return class `A` after populating properties values

```
public A GetPopulatedValues()
{
     //code to populate values here
}
```

Now my question is, how to assign all the property values at once?

This works

```
public void Init()
{
   var obj = new B();
   obj.Prop1 = GetPopulatedValues().Prop1;
}
```

But i want something like this

```
  public void Init()
{
   var obj = new B();
   obj = GetPopulatedValues();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a constructor:

```
public Foo(string prop1, string prop2)
{
    Prop1 = prop1;
    Prop2 = prop2;
}
```

Or a copy constructor:

```
public Foo(Foo other)
{
    Prop1 = other.Prop1;
    Prop2 = other.Prop2;
}
```

Or use an object initializer:

```
var foo = new Foo { Prop1 = "Hello", Prop2 = "World" };
```

But as @RudiVisser says, you'll actually want to fix this in the `GetPopulatedValues()` method, by supplying a reference to the object you want to populate:

```
static class FooPopulator
{
    public static void PopulateValues(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Prop1 = "Hello";
        foo.Prop2 = "World";
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
FooPopulator.PopulateValues(foo);
```

Now your `foo` object is usable and populatable, without having to alter the `Foo` class. Added bonus: when you add a property to populate (say `Prop3`), you will only have to alter the `PopulateValues()` method.

In your code you also have to do that, but then you'd need to also add the `Prop3` assignment, which, if forgotten, will cause bugs.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @CodeCaster that this should probably be done with a constructor modification, but just to provide another alternative - why not make your `GetPopulatedValues` method accept an instance of `A`, and populate the values directly.

```
public void GetPopulatedValues(A instance)
{
    instance.Prop1 = (whatever);
}

public void Init()
{
    var obj = new B();
    GetPopulatedValues(obj);
}
```